# Best method to dynamically draw static image without pre-defined size

Tags: android

I am writing an App that need to render an image if a user selects an option.  The image will read a data file and according to the contents of the data file render an appropriate amount of rectangles, lines and text (I'm visualizing data).  I read this site [Drawables or Canavs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) and if I understood it correctly it says I should use drawables.  But what I don't understand (haven't found where or missed it) is where I define the space to draw shapes in.  As I do not know the number of shapes and thus the size of the entire visualization until I read the data file, i do not know how large of a composite image (size required to render all of the shapes and lines) I need.

So I have three questions.

Should I use drawables to accomplish what I need to do?
Does the `mDrawable.setBounds` method define the 'size' of the visualization I am working in
Can I draw lines and insert text with drawables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a Drawable you would use an ImageView with the source set to a drawable, or some other UI component with the background set to the drawable, or override the onDraw method of a custom UI View of your own and use the Drawable#draw(Canvas) call to draw the Drawable to the canvas and thus the view that is using that canvas to draw itself. The Drawable#setBounds method defines where on the canvas the Drawable#draw method draws to.

Generally, in your situation, Drawable wouldn't be used at all. Rather you would just subclass View, override onDraw(Canvas), and make your drawing calls directly on the Canvas object. This object has drawBitmap, drawLines, drawText, etc. methods:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText(java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)

Comment: Thanks.  One clarification on one of my original questions:  Can I draw outside of the field of view and essentially have an image that requires one to scroll in some direction (say down) to see the entire picture?  Essentially I'd like to draw an image that is larger than the real estate the screen provides.  Is there a maximum (x, y) point to which I can draw?

Comment: You can have your View that subclasses onDraw inside another view like a ScrollView that contains children larger than itself and manages scrolling around them. The Canvas object has a clipping function, so draw calls would be ignored outside the actual visible part, but on scrolling invalidate would be called and you can update. Alternatively you can draw to a Bitmap via a Canvas made by the Canvas(Bitmap) constructor as well and just show the bitmap as an image in many UI controls that will handle all the rest - zooming, panning, etc..